# react native video processing - crashing in release build

Tags: react-native

i am using a library - react-native-video-processing. Its working fine in debug mode, but when creating a release mode, getting an error form this library -

```
ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl caught native exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke RNTrimmerManager.getVideoInfo
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:193)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:149)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeContext" in class "Lwseemann/media/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever;" or its superclasses
        at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.native_init(Native Method)
        at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.<clinit>(Unknown Source:43)
        at com.shahenlibrary.Trimmer.a.p(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.shahenlibrary.Trimmer.TrimmerManager.getVideoInfo(Unknown Source:24)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:149) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2021-01-08 17:49:35.583 7482-7743/? E/unknown:DisabledDevSupportManager: Caught exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke RNTrimmerManager.getVideoInfo
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:193)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:149)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeContext" in class "Lwseemann/media/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever;" or its superclasses
        at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.native_init(Native Method)
        at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.<clinit>(Unknown Source:43)
        at com.shahenlibrary.Trimmer.a.p(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.shahenlibrary.Trimmer.TrimmerManager.getVideoInfo(Unknown Source:24)
```

i tried looking more into it. But was unable to find any specific reason for that.
any help on this or someone facing the same issue?